# list is a subset of another list

Tags: python, list, subset

in Python, given two lists of pairs:

```
listA = [ [1,20], [3,19], [37,11], [21,17] ]
listB = [ [1,20], [21,17] ]
```

how do you efficiently write a python function which return True if listB is a subset of listA?  oh and [1,20] pair is equivalent to [20,1]

Comment: Is [ [1,20], [2,30] ] equivalent to [ [2,30], [1,20] ] ?

Comment: can these lists contain anything at all, or will they always contain numbers?  If always numbers, will these numbers always be positive?

Comment: @sean-vieira -- yes the numbers are always positive; and @threed -- the order doesn't matter so the lists are equivalent

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `frozenset`.

```
>>> listA = [ [1,20], [3,19], [37,11], [21,17] ]
>>> listB = [ [1,20], [21,17] ]

>>> setA = frozenset([frozenset(element) for element in listA])
>>> setB = frozenset([frozenset(element) for element in listB])

>>> setA
frozenset([frozenset([17, 21]), frozenset([1, 20]), frozenset([11, 37]), frozens
et([19, 3])])
>>> setB
frozenset([frozenset([17, 21]), frozenset([1, 20])])

>>> setB <= setA
True
```

Comment: +1 -- Better to use the built in methods than re-invent the wheel!

Answer (score 8):

Just in order to offer an alternative, perhaps using tuple and set is more efficient:

```
>>> set(map(tuple,listB)) <= set(map(tuple,listA))
True
```